# Inject CSS into UWP WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I have a Windows 10 UWP app that has a WebView that is loading a page from public web site like this: `this.webView.Navigate(new Uri(url));`. I have injected some JavaScript into the page to augment it and I would like to inject some CSS. I know I can use JavaScript to simply inject a `<script>` tag with the CSS read from a file in in it. However, that doesn't work well when it comes to images referenced in the CSS.

I've tried `<link>`ing the CSS with a protocol of `ms-appx-web` and I've tried directly inserting the CSS with the `url()` property values using protocol of `ms-appx-web`, but those methods don't seem to work.

Ideally what I'd like is to just insert a `<link>` into the web page that works and who's internal relative `url()` property values (like for `backghround-image`) just work.

The only other option that I can think of is to base64-encode all the images directly into the CSS file via some pre-processing. However, I don't know of any tools that can automatically pre-process CSS link that (UPDATE: now I do: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-css) and I'm not thrilled about the idea either.

Comment: How did you load your html page ? Which method of the webview control did you use ?

Comment: @ArnaudDevelay I've added that information in the last edit to my question